# Find and replace multiple base64 images with filenames

Tags: php, laravel, image, base64

Before I start, I am using Laravel 5.7 for my project but any php solution would work.
I am making a simple editor on my site where user can do simple editing along with adding images. I am using contenteditable div for this purpose. When I add images to the div it gets added as base64 image. After submitting the form  I want to save those images as files on server side and then want to replace the src of those images with the path to newly save images in the string before saving it in database. I didn't find a way to submit contenteditable div so I am transfering all the text from div to a hidden textarea before submitting. correct me if there is any other reliable way of doing that.
Here is what I am looking for:

**Original sample content of textarea in request :-**

```
"This is a test post with some images like this one 
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j.....long base 64 string...." id="img02">
and it can contain more than one images like here is the second image
<img src="data:image/png;base64,/8Aue.....long base 64 string...." id="img01">
and more images like this"
```

**Intended output :-**

```
"This is a test post with some images like this one  
<img src="my_public_path/Unique_file_name.jpg" id="img02"> 
and it can contain more than one images like here is the second image 
<img src="my_public_path/Unique_file_name.png" id="img01"> 
and more images like this"
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction or provide me with the php code to achieve this?

Comment: What editor are you using to add the images? A lot of editors have a way built in to store images on amazon s3, digital ocean spaces or your own server.

Comment: I am making my own editor and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: Gotcha. So you will need to decide if you want to store images on the fly, or store them when you save everything. For example using amazon s3 and their sdk, you would be able to upload the image and then get the full URL in the callback. Then you could use javascript to grab the element by id and replace with the new string.

Comment: I want to store everything at the end as there could be many edits before user finally store the post. I want to keep the images in base64 format until user decide to store it. At that time I want to convert base64 images to files, store them and replace src with saved image path.

Comment: To keep the things simple, I also tried to use hidden file inputs with fakepath for each image used in text as base64 and pass those in request and I can successfully save those files on server side but the problem is how can I replace src of base64 image with path to those saved images. I use similar ids for both eg. file input id is "img01" for the corresponding base64 image with id "image01". If that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually solved my problem with following code. I am posting it here just in case someone else need it.

```
$stt = $request->storytextTemp; // string containing base64 encoded image files.
preg_match('#data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]++)#', $stt, $x);
while(isset($x[0]))
{
    $imgdata = base64_decode($x[0]);
    $info = explode(";", explode("/", $x[0])[1])[0];
    $textareaImages = $request->imagesTextarea;

    $imm = Image::make(file_get_contents($x[0]));
    $imp = public_path().'/images/tempStoryImages/';
    $imn = date('y_m_d') . "_" . uniqid().".".$info;
    $imm->save($imp.$imn);

    $stt = str_replace($x[0], 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/tempStoryImages/'.$imn, $stt);
    preg_match('#data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]++)#', $stt, $x);
}
return $stt;
```

Above programe save all my images in tempStoryImages folder and return html to show all image files. I can now store this returned string into database with image path embeded into it.